Does az login require --tenant now?
Running Azure CLI on a Windows 10 machine. I have one tenant/directory and one subscription.
I'm having trouble using the standard az login command. I do have the latest version of Azure CLI:
$ az upgrade --all
This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
You already have the latest azure-cli version: 2.64.0
Upgrade finished.You can enable auto-upgrade with 'az config set auto-upgrade.enable=yes'. More details in https://docs.microsoft.com/cli/azure/update-azure-cli#automatic-update

Here's what happens when I try to log in:
$ az login
Select the account you want to log in with. For more information on login with Azure CLI, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2271136
Authentication failed against tenant {MY_TENANT_ID} 'Default Directory': (pii). Status: Response_Status.Status_InteractionRequired, Error code: 3399614476, Tag: 557973645
If you need to access subscriptions in the following tenants, please use `az login --tenant TENANT_ID`.
{MY_TENANT_ID} 'Default Directory'
No subscriptions found for {MY_GLOBAL_ADMIN_USER}.

Login using the --tenant flag works, but comes with a strange message.
$ az login --tenant {MY_TENANT_ID}
Select the account you want to log in with. For more information on login with Azure CLI, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2271136
[
  {MY_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILS}
]

I verify that that login was successful using az account show, which gives me the exact same subscription details.
This gives me the impression that the standard az login command has been disabled, but I can't find anything about this online.

I found a solution:
az config set core.enable_broker_on_windows=false

Now, try az login again. The command above disables the Web Account Manager (WAM) on Windows, which interferes with the login process. A welcome side-effect for me was that I no longer have to type my account name (email) every time I log in, which I had to do with the WAM.
Unfortunately, I have no explanation for why WAM interferes with the login. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli-interactively#sign-in-with-web-account-manager-wam-on-windows
